# Cannot get validation working with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot application (using version 1.2.3) with 1 controller that shows a form. This all works fine, but now I want to add validation. I have this method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/licensing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doRegistration( @Valid CustomerLicenseRegistration customerLicenseRegistration, Model model, BindingResult bindingResult )
{
    if( bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
        logger.debug( "There are errors! {}", bindingResult );
        return "customer/license-registration";
    }
    logger.debug( "customerLicenseRegistration: " + customerLicenseRegistration );
    CustomerLicense customerLicense = m_licenseService.createCustomerLicense( customerLicenseRegistration );
    model.addAttribute( "customerLicense", customerLicense );
    return "customer/license-registration-done";
}
```

If I now type something invalid, I get the "Whitelabel error page" after submit and my breakpoint inside the method is never hit (If I remove the `@Valid` annotation, the breakpoint does get hit). The error page shows:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon May 18 09:42:27 CEST 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='customerLicenseRegistration'. Error count: 1
```

Spring seems to notice that the object is not valid, but it does not show the form again so the user can fix his mistake. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Found the answer due to [the tutorial here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171125150757/http://codetutr.com/2013/05/28/spring-mvc-form-validation/). I have to change my method signature from:

```
public String doRegistration( @Valid CustomerLicenseRegistration customerLicenseRegistration, 
Model model, 
BindingResult bindingResult )
```

to:

```
public String doRegistration( @Valid CustomerLicenseRegistration customerLicenseRegistration, 
BindingResult bindingResult, 
Model model )
```

Notice how the `BindingResult` has to be *immediately* after the object I have annotated with `@Valid`.

Comment: Thanks buddy for answer. I put hours in understanding what was the problem and it came with just method signature mis match. Work for me. thanks. :)

Comment: sure. I just forgot in happiness :)

Comment: Thanks :)
These are the things that annoy me in spring hahahah

Comment: In my case everything worked well until I changed form encoding type to multipart. The signature change resolved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: The tutorilal link is died

Comment: Updated link to archive from wayback machine as the link is indeed dead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was wrong input to the input box. Actually i entered **"-"** special character in the **input box** which throws same error -**Validation failed for object='events'. Error count: 5**. 
I resolved it by entering *numerical/String* values.