# Javax @Valid annotation doesn't work as expected

Tags: spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a for with object creation. When I trying to create it and validate - I receiving an error, but not on the UI side, as expected. Don't understand why.

Here is my html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      lang="en"
      layout:decorate="~{layout/layout}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Добавить Объект</title>
</head>
<body>
<main class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form method="POST" th:action="@{/admin/objects/add}" th:object="${objectForm}">
            <p class="h4 text-left">Добавить объект</p>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 offset-md-0"
                 th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}? 'has-error':''">
                <label for="exampleInputName"></label>
                <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName" required="required"
                       placeholder="Название(ручной ввод)"
                       th:field="*{name}"/>
                <br/>
                <p class="alert alert-danger"
                   th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}"
                   th:errors="*{name}">Validation error</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-1 offset-md-0">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success offset-md-0 btn-sm active">Создать</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

ObjectController:

```
@Controller
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/admin/objects")
public class ObjectController {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ObjectController.class);
    private final ObjectsService objectsService;
    private Pageable pageable;
    
    @Autowired
    public ObjectController(ObjectsService objectsService) {
        this.objectsService = objectsService;
    }

@GetMapping("/add")
    public String printAddObject(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("objectForm",
                           new Object()
                          );
        return "objects_add";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addNewObject(@ModelAttribute("objectForm") @Valid Object objectForm,
                               Model model,
                               BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + bindingResult.getAllErrors().toString());
            return "objects_add";
        }
        if (!objectsService.create(objectForm)) {
            bindingResult.addError(new FieldError("objectForm",
                                                  "name",
                                                  "Объект с таким именем уже существует"
            ));
            return "objects_add";
        }
        return "redirect:/admin/objects";
    }
```

Object class:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity(name = "objects")
public @Data class Object {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "object_id")
    private Long objectId;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name; 
}
```

When I'm clicking on submit Button and inputing one symbol, I am expecting that UI will show me an error message, but all I can see:

[Browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfLA3.png)

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORDv7.png)

What I am doing wrong?

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.eco.products.waste</groupId>
    <artifactId>waste-web</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>products-waste-web-client</name>
    <description>Eco-Waste-Products Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>29.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
<!--            <optional>true</optional>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.18</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot get validation working with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297719/cannot-get-validation-working-with-spring-boot-and-thymeleaf)

Comment: I made changes, and place binding result right after the @Valid object6 but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong:

1. Binging Result must be right after the Object that is marked @Valid
2. @Validated annotation shall no be used.